# c read a file's permissions

Tags: c, permissions

How can I check if a file has read permissions in C?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `access(2)` in POSIX.  In Standard C, the best you can do is try to open it with `fopen()` and see if it succeeds.

If `fopen()` returns `NULL`, you can try to use `errno` to distinguish between the "File does not exist" (`errno == ENOENT`) and "Permission denied" (`errno == EACCES`) cases - but unfortunately those two `errno` values are only defined by POSIX as well.

(Even on POSIX, in most cases the best thing to do is try to open the file, then look at why it failed, because using `access()` introduces an obvious race condition).

Comment: I would use fopen(), but I need to be able to tell the difference whether the file isnt readable and whether it doesnt exist

Comment: Using fopen will be better. Because access is vulnerable to TOCTOU attacks. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOCTOU). If that is a concern in your case at all.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a fan of using [stat()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html), myself.

Comment: The questioner asked how to read a file's permissions.  The stat() function returns the file's permissions.  The fstat() function returns the file's permissions given its opened file handle.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [access()](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/access/) function:

```
if (access(pathname, R_OK) == 0)
{
    /* It's readable by the current user. */
}
```

`errno` will be set to `ENOENT` if the file doesn't exist, or `EACCES` if it exists but isn't accessible to the current user.  See [the manual page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/access/) for more error codes.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check a files permissions.

A very simple method for finding out the permissions is [int access(const char *path, int amode)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/access/). As commented before, this method operates unless there is an error. There are a few flags that you may use:

> F_OK: Used to check for existence of file.
>
> R_OK: Used to check for read permission bit.
>
> W_OK: Used to check for write permission bit.
>
> X_OK: Used to check for execute permission bit.

When the file doesn't have the correct permissions, an error is thrown that you can retrive with errno.

```
int fd = access("sample.txt", F_OK); 
if(fd == -1){ 
        printf("Error Number : %d\n", errno); 
    perror("Error Description:"); 
}
```

If you want to handle an error while retrieving a file address, use [FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm). Like access() it has flags that you can check such as read or write. The difference is, fopen can use strings instead of constants and will return a FILE pointer.

```
FILE *pf = fopen ("fileName.txt", "rb");
```

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_error_handling.htm) is a good example of how to handle errors with fopen

A third file checking method is [int chmod(const char *path, mode_t mode)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/rtchm.htm). chmod() is more useful than access() since it has more flags. Depending on what directory you are reading from it could be easier to just use access() but if you have many files of different permissions then chmod() would be more useful.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
int chmod(const char *path, mode_t mode);
```

I know that this post is from 11 years ago. I just wanted to make a general synopsis of common file handling methods.